# How to rebuild a master table from derived, filtered tables?

Tags: correlation, cross-validation, contingency-tables

*Disclaimer: I'm a developer, so please forgive-me if I'm not aware of math and statistics terminology.*

Once upon a time there was a master table with this layout:

```
City      Car     Fruit   Count
===============================
Dallas    Ford    Lemon    10
Dallas    Chevy   Lemon     5
Portland  Ford    Lemon     7
Portland  Chevy   Grapes   19
Dallas    Ford    Grapes   13
```

Somebody decided to "optimize" into 3 tables: one without City, another without Car, and another without Fruit. For instance, the one without City would be:

```
Car     Fruit   Count
=====================
Ford    Lemon    17
Chevy   Lemon     5
Chevy   Grapes   19
Ford    Grapes   13
```

As you can see, the two rows with Ford and Lemon were combined into a single one, with the sum of count. The same happened with the other two "optimized" tables.

My question is, given I have the "optimized" tables, is there some algorithm or procedure that can bring me back the master table, even if I accept some error in the Count value?

Comment: Matrix algebra.

Comment: So, based on all two-dimensional projections, you would like to find/approximate the underlying three-dimensional structure?

Comment: Provided that all the information is still contained in those three tables, whicch appears to be the case here, then reconstruction becomes a matter of solving simultaneous equations to put Humpty Dumpty back together again. It is a pain to do, but just algebra.

Comment: See https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d213/271cb443791e615400e21f799b34e66d19fd.pdf